# How to make a corresponding div visible once a reply button is clicked on that post ad?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

Any help/direction is appreciated.
(If something does not make sense below, let me know.I will try my best to clarify)

**issue:**
I am unable to make corresponding div visible when user click on the reply button for that ad post.
div element display= none (by default).

**Code walk through:**
I have a html code where it displays all the posts from database using a loop(I am using ejs format to render data to browser).
All post have a reply button.
If a user click on a reply button, the corresponding div should become visible (where user can send the reply to the post.)

**Technology stack:** (In case it is needed)
I am using Nodejs+express with .ejs/css to render data to web browser.
database as mongodb

**(Note:There are multiple reply buttons since all posts has one reply button)**

Html code:

```
<article>
      <% for(var i=0; i<postList.length; i++) { %>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <h1><%= postList[i].title %></h1>
          <a href="" data-id="<%= postList[i]._id %>" class="delete">delete</a>
          <a href="" data-id="<%= postList[i]._id %>" class="edit">edit</a>
          <p><%= postList[i].description %></p>
          <h4><%= postList[i].pincode %></h4>
          <h4><%= postList[i].address %></h4>
          <button class="reply-button">Reply</button><br>
          <!--class reply-block is hidden by default-->
          <!--This div should become visible when user clicks on the above reply  button-->
          <div class="reply-block">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
            <button class="reply-submit" data-id="<%= postList[i]._id %>">send</button>
            <button class="reply-cancel">cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <% } %>
    </article>
```

Comment: Is your web page using jQuery or some UI framework?

Comment: I am using jQuery.

Comment: call function on click event of reply button and make that class visible using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can insert this Javascript in `<script>` tags after your article HTML:

```
$(".reply-button").click(function(e) {
    // make corresponding reply-block visible
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".reply-block").show();

    // other code here to act on the click
});
```

The `.closest(".container")` walks up the parent tree to find the closest `.container` and then uses `.find(".reply-block")` to find the reply-block in that container and then uses `.show()` to make it visible.

This assumes you have it as `display:none` and that's the way you hid it.  If you hid it some other way, then you will have to change  how you make it visible to correspond to however you made it hidden.

Comment: Thanks jfriend000. It worked like a charm :). And it will be great if you know any books/websites where I can read and understand concepts like "this", "closest" etc?

Comment: @KasidKhan - Just follow the jQuery tag here on stackoverflow and read other people's solutions.  Then, try to tackle some questions yourself and pour over the jQuery doc to see what features might help you with a new problem.  The jQuery doc is pretty well organized into categories of features.  That's how I learned it.  I'm sure Google would show you a bunch of "learning jQuery" web sites, if that's what else you're looking for.  I don't have any favorites.